# Firebase observe slow for large database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app displaying places (downloaded from firebase) based on user location.

I have currently 5k entries and they are displayed in about 10seconds.
I plan to have 80k entries and I don't want users to wait that long.

**What I did :**
I created a Place class, I do 'observe'(.value) on my firebase ref and on each child I put each element in an attribute of the Place class.
Then the place:Place = Place(attributes) id added to an array:Place until all places have been downloaded.

```
self.ref.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                        for place in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
```

When all places are in the array I compare places locations with the user location and sort the array to display them by distance in a tableview.

**What I tried:**
I also tried to use GeoFire but it is slower.

How the db looks like (80k elements) :

```
{
"users": {
    "DFkjdhfgYG": {
         "id":"DFkjdhfgYG"
        ,"key2":"value"
        ,"key3":"value"
        ,"key4":"value"
        ,"key5":"value"
        ,"key6":"value"
        ,"key7":"value"
        ,"key8":"value"
        ,"key9":"value"
        ,"key10":"value"
        ,"key11":"value"
        ,"key12":value
        ,"key13":value
        ,"key14":"value"
        ,"key15":"value"
        ,"key16":"value"
        ,"key17":"value"
        ,"key18":"value"
        ,"key19":"value"
        ,"key20":"value"
        ,"key21":value
        ,"key22":value
        ,"key23":value
        ,"key24":value
        ,"key25":value
        ,"key26":"value"
        ,"key27":value
        ,"key28":value
        ,"key29":"value"
        },
     "BVvfdTRZ": {
         "id":"BVvfdTRZ"
        ,"key2":"value"
        ,"key3":"value"
        ,"key4":"value"
        ,"key5":"value"
        ,"key6":"value"
        ,"key7":"value"
        ,"key8":"value"
        ,"key9":"value"
        ,"key10":"value"
        ,"key11":"value"
        ,"key12":value
        ,"key13":value
        ,"key14":"value"
        ,"key15":"value"
        ,"key16":"value"
        ,"key17":"value"
        ,"key18":"value"
        ,"key19":"value"
        ,"key20":"value"
        ,"key21":value
        ,"key22":value
        ,"key23":value
        ,"key24":value
        ,"key25":value
        ,"key26":"value"
        ,"key27":value
        ,"key28":value
        ,"key29":"value"
        }
  }
}
```

Now I don't know what to do and I absolutely need to user Firebase.

Can you help me to improve the way I download firebase db elements, or to show me another way to do it, to make the whole process faster ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You're using a for loop in a function that is being called the same number of times as there are children in your database path, making the for loop completely useless and overkill, which can add extra time to the whole process.

Another thing that you can do is have this be called on a different thread and making it the highest priority over the rest of your code. Here's how to do both of those:

```
func handleFirebase() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        self.ref.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            let key = snapshot.key

            print("KEY: \(key), VALUE: \(value)")

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond ! I'm sorry but I can't make your code work, nothing is printed in the console

Comment: It's a little difficult to say what can be wrong without seeing your ref path. If your ref goes to .child('id") then you'll simply want to change .observe(.value) to .observe(.childAdded)

Comment: My ref : ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

Comment: @scienst If 'id' is inside "users", then you'll want to use .child("users")..child("id") and then tweak your code to what mentioned in the last comment. As long as you're inside "id", it will work

Comment: You're talking about the "id" in the json in my first message ? Because each child has its own id

Comment: I updated the json for you to better understand, sorry if I was not clear

Comment: I have managed to make your code work and the data is displayed much faster nevertheless when data is displayed the app freezes for few seconds… any idea ? Thanks !